# Is it possible to generate vector based pdf using wordcloud

Tags: python, word-cloud

I am using [wordcloud](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud) in python to generate word clouds.

I was able to reproduce this [example](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/blob/master/examples/simple.py) on my machine, and then tried to change the last line `plt.show()` to `plt.savefig('image.pdf')` to have a pdf output.

I had a pdf with the same result, however, the pdf seems like pixel-based instead of vector-based. When I focus a particular point in the pdf it becomes a very low-quality picture.

Is there any way to produce vector-based pdf using wordcloud? If not, is there any other library that I can produce vector-based (pdf) wordclouds in Python?

Comment: Do you want a PDF specifically, or would a vector postscript file be fine?

Comment: @jonnybazookatone I need a pdf.

Comment: You can be interested in this https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/issues/493

Answer (score 2):

If wordcloud can generate any sort of vector output such as ps or svg, inkscape can usually convert it to a PDF without rasterizing it.  You can even do this headless, e.g. inkscape my.svg -A my.pdf.

Hmm, looking at wordcloud, it looks like it uses PIL.  I don't think that PIL can produce vector images.  But if you could use the logic in wordcloud and separate it from PIL, you can get vector fonts onto PDFs by drawing onto a reportlab canvas.

Answer (score -1):

You can save the images in a vector format so that they will be scalable without quality loss. Such formats are PDF and EPS. Just change the extension to .pdf or .eps and matplotlib will write the correct image format.

```
plt.savefig('destination_path.eps', format='eps')
plt.savefig('destination_path.pdf', format='pdf')
```

I have found that eps/pdf files work best.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, `dpi` stands for dots per inch, which does not make sense for a vector-based graphic. Having a better quality (more dots) does not mean that you actually have a vector-based image. -1.

Comment: The dpi parameter is an optional param. With eps and pdf params the image/pdf defaults to vector format.

Comment: You can see the link for more clarification http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig

Comment: So? I couldn't understand your argument. Are we clear on the fact that `dpi` does not make any sense for vector based graphics?